# Spry Tabbed Panels, Tabs aren't touching Content

Tags: spry, panels, tabbed

I am working on a site with Spry Tabbed Pannels. My problem is that I can't get my .TabbedPanelsTab, .TabbedPanelsSelected, TabbedPanelsHover, and .TabbedPanelsTab a, to touch the .TabbedPanelsContentGroup.

There is a very thin white line in between the two and I've tried lots of things, like a negative margin, or an extra thick border. And nothing seems to work.

My tabs have images in them for design purposes, so that's just a heads up.

Here is the site for reference:

http://emilymagnuson.com/trustbank/index.html

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is within your .TabbedPanelsContentGroup:

> change the padding-top from 3px to 0px.

Let me know if I misunderstood your query.